# How do I add anti-clickjacking support to an app I'm building in webapp2 for google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2, clickjacking

I know there's WSGI middleware for django, but I can't find anything for webapp2. Would the django middleware work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the same behavior that django provides with webapp2, you only need to add the following header to the response:

self.response.headers["X-Frame-Options"] = "SAMEORIGIN"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options